# How do i display sympy equation without calculation?

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
sample_expression=2*x+y-z 
a=int(input('enter integer:'))
b=int(input('enter integer:')) 
c=int(input('enter integer:'))
print(sympify(sample_expression.subs(x,a).subs(y,b).subs(z,c),evaluate=False))
```

How do I go about displaying the expression without sympy calculating the values?
for eg if a=1,b,=2.z=3
how do I display the expression "2*1+2-3" instead of the computed value "1"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbol trickery by creating symbols from the values, e.g.

```
>>> Symbol(str(2)) + Symbol(str(3))
2 + 3
```

You can create the expression in an evaluate=False context

```
>>> eq=S('2*x + y + z')
>>> with evaluate(False):
...  f = eq.subs({x:1,y:2,z:3})
...
>>> f
2 + 2*1 + 3
```